# Why is there no std::erase function in C++20. G++ MSYS2 Windows

Tags: c++, string, iterator, erase

Apparently std::erase was added in C++20, but my compiler isn't letting me use it for some reason.

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1, num2 = 0;
    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    vector<char> vec_num1(to_string(num1).begin(), to_string(num1).end());
    vector<char> vec_num2(to_string(num2).begin(), to_string(num2).end());

    std::erase(vec_num1, "0");
    std::erase(vec_num2, "0");

    int removezero1, removezero2, removezerosum = 0;

    for (int v : vec_num1) {
        removezero1 = removezero1 * 10 + v;
    }
    for (int v : vec_num1) {
        removezero2 = removezero2 * 10 + v;
    }
    for (int v : vec_num1) {
        removezerosum = removezerosum * 10 + v;
    }

    if (removezero1 + removezero2 == removezerosum)
    {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }


}
```

error

> main.cpp:16:10: error: 'erase' is not a member of 'std'
> 16 |     std::erase(vec_num1, "0");
> |          ^~~~~
> main.cpp:17:10: error: 'erase' is not a member of 'std'
> 17 |     std::erase(vec_num2, "0");
> |          ^~~~~

gcc version 12.2.0

Comment: I haven't checked but it's entirely possible that gcc just hasn't implemented this specific function yet. It sometimes takes years for a new C++ standard to be fully implemented in gcc.

Comment: That's disappointing. Seemed like such a nice function. Will have to do it the long way now.

Comment: You mean `std::erase` and not `std::erased` (which does not exist at all)

Comment: Yes I mean std::erase. that is the code I wrote

Comment: Yes but why adding a 'd' in the title and in the question then ?

Comment: It looks like you forget to add `-std=c++20` to command line. Also, you have `std::vector<char>`, but trying to erase string. It should be `std::erase(vec_num1, '0');`. See working example: https://godbolt.org/z/qxqKocc69

Comment: Implemented in gcc 9 according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Also, `vector<char> vec_num1(to_string(num1).begin(), to_string(num1).end());` is wrong code. You can't do this. You need to do something line: `string tmp = to_string(num1); vector<char> vec_num1(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());`

Comment: what flags to you pass to the compiler?

Comment: -std=gnu++20 pass this flag.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is running!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it follows from the error message

> main.cpp:16:10: error: 'erase' is not a member of 'std' 16 |
> std::erase(vec_num1, "0"); | ^~~~~ main.cpp:17:10: error: 'erase' is
> not a member of 'std' 17 | std::erase(vec_num2, "0"); | ^~~~~

you are compiling the program by the compiler that uses C++17 features.

You need to say the compiler to use C++ 20 features as for example -std=c++20.

But in any case your code is wrong because at least in these declarations

```
vector<char> vec_num1(to_string(num1).begin(), to_string(num1).end());
vector<char> vec_num2(to_string(num2).begin(), to_string(num2).end());
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

there are used iterators of different sequences of temporary created objects. That is there are used invalid ranges.

You need to create intermediate string objects as for example

```
auto s1 = std::to_string( num1 );
vector<char> vec_num1(s1.begin(), s1.end());
auto s2 = std::to_string( num2 );
vector<char> vec_num2(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

And the calls of the function std::erase are also wrong. For example instead of

```
std::erase(vec_num1, "0");
std::erase(vec_num2, "0");
```

you need to write

```
std::erase(vec_num1, '0');
std::erase(vec_num2, '0');
```

That is instead of string literals you have to use character literals because the value type of the vectors is `char`.

Also in this declaration

```
int removezero1, removezero2, removezerosum = 0;
```

there is initialized by zero only the last declarator `removezerosum`. You need to write

```
int removezero1 = 0, removezero2 = 0, removezerosum = 0;
```

Also the header

```
#include <string.h>
```

is redundant. Remove it.